# How to show a list with scrollbar in php

Tags: php, html, list

```
<?php foreach ( $fields as $name => $value ): 
    if ( $name == 'Firm Name' ):
        ?>
        <dt> <?php echo $name ?> </dt>
        <dd class="tribe-meta-value"> <?php echo $value ?> </dd>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

the output for this code will be..

Firm Name:
firm1,firm2,firm3..

variable `$value` is giving the firm names that are stored in database.

I want to show these firm name in a list with scrollbar.. How to do this??

Comment: check css property overflow-y: auto;

Comment: @talsibony ..the value for this variable $value in database is like firm1,firm2,firm3.. so when i am running this code it simply outputs the same format  firm1,firm2,firm3.... i want the firm names to be printed in a list.. i think i have to do change in the code for this..

Comment: Generally, formatting issues like this aren't as much a job for PHP as they are for client-side technologies like JavaScript. Maybe you should explain further what you mean by "list with scrollbar". Then somebody might be able to point you to what HTML code your PHP needs to generate, and whether a browser renders it directly the way you want or whether you need to apply some JavaScript to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
    <style>
    #div{
      border:1px solid #000;
      font-family:arial;
      height:100px;
      width:200px;
    }
    ul{
      list-style:none;
      max-height:100px;
      margin:0;
      overflow:auto;
      padding:0;
      text-indent:10px;
    }
    li{
      line-height:25px;
    }
    li:nth-child(even){
      background:#eee;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="div"> 

    <?php
    $options = "Firm1, Firm2, Firm3";
    $options = explode(',', $options);
    ?>
    <ul>

        <?php
        foreach ($options AS $value) {
        ?>
            <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>

        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: this is showing the output as a Select list.. i want the output to be in a simle unordered list.

Comment: Thanks.. now it showing in a list with bullet.. one more thing i want the list to be scrollable and without bullets..

Comment: Do you have a example?

Comment: I have updated my answer again. See if that's you mean.

Comment: This list is dynamic list.. as the value for firm name will increase dynamically.. So if the list will appear like this only then the webpage will become scrollable.. for this issue i want the list to become scrollable.

Comment: Well, my answer should make the list scrollable and not the hole page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be i understood your need. Let me know on comments.

Just remove the borders From tables according to you visual needs

Css

```
 .scrollit {
overflow:scroll;
height:100px;
 }
```

Php

```
  <?php
  ?>

 <table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="200">Firm names</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td >
    <div class="scrollit">
        <table>

 <?php 

       foreach ( $fields as $name => $value ): 
         if ( $name == 'Firm Name' ):
 ?>

     <tr><td width="200"><?php echo $value ?></td></tr>
<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
  </table>
    </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```